# Xcode: Instruments 4.0 requires Mac OS X 10.7 Lion?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, instruments

I just got a company MacBook and started learning Xcode. When I tried to launch this "Instruments" tool, I got the following error message:

[image]

But I already have Mac OS X 10.7:

[image]

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you re-install your Developer Tools.

To uninstall all Xcode developer tools:

```
sudo Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

Comment: before you do this restart your computer